# Table borders are not visible inside expandable list content

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I just started learning HTML and copied a code to create an expandable-collapsible list. In the list content, I have created a table, but the borders of that table are not visible when I open the web page. The same table displays fine with border when I run it on a webpage without the list. Please help me solve the problem. The code is shown below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i><h5> <a>Leader </a></h5></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">

                        Sample Line

                        Course Description
                        <p>The best brains compete to get an admission to this two-year legendary course offered by us. The course, unmatched in its rigour and precision, raises you to the very zenith of your preparation. The stimulating atmosphere of the institute, small batches (yes-we believe in quality) and one to one interaction with the instructor ensure that every rough edge is smoothened, every small doubt is cleared. More importantly, we train you to think analytically, we give you a systematic approach to problem solving . If you think you are bright, if you think you are capable, if you think that you can make it to the top, this course is precisely for you.
                        </p>


                        <table
style="text-align: left; width: 718px; height: 139px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
border=10 BORDERCOLOR=RED cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); font-weight: bold;">Mode
of Admission<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1"
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">Through
BOOST <br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); font-weight: bold;">Phases<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">Phase
1<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">Phase
2<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); font-weight: bold;">Commencement
Date<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">7
April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">28
April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); font-weight: bold;">Last
of Registration<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">5
April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">26
April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); font-weight: bold;">Last
Date of Refund<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">20
April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td
style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);">10
May 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code contains the table, which displays fine. Where's the list?

Comment: I am sorry. The complete code is is now added. Please help.

Comment: Please correctly indent your code. You also missed te closing list `</ul>` tag and a closing `</div>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example what a collapsible list looks like:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_lists_collapsible

You can use javascript like jQuery to get it done fast.

Your table looks fine.

**EDIT:**

The problems are in your styling. I've modified your approach a little so the table is styled with a css class named "table-style". Table cells are also styled using classes "table-cell-1" and "table-cell-2". Now you have a better view on the styling in css. Copy paste and test the sample. Give it a thumbs up if this is what you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <style>
            .table-style {
                text-align: left; 
                width: 718px; 
                height: 139px; 
                margin-left: auto; 
                margin-right: auto;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 10px;
                border-color: red; 
                cellpadding: 2;
                cellspacing: 2;
            }
            .table-cell-1 {
                vertical-align: top; 
                text-align: center; 
                background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); 
                font-weight: bold;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: red; 
            }
            .table-cell-2 {
                vertical-align: top; 
                text-align: center; 
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 51);
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: red; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i><h5> <a>Leader </a></h5></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        Sample Line
                        Course Description
                        <p>The best brains compete to get an admission to this two-year legendary course offered by us. The course, unmatched in its rigour and precision, raises you to the very zenith of your preparation. The stimulating atmosphere of the institute, small batches (yes-we believe in quality) and one to one interaction with the instructor ensure that every rough edge is smoothened, every small doubt is cleared. More importantly, we train you to think analytically, we give you a systematic approach to problem solving . If you think you are bright, if you think you are capable, if you think that you can make it to the top, this course is precisely for you.
                        </p>
                        <table class="table-style">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table-cell-1">Mode of Admission<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" class="table-cell-2">Through BOOST <br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table-cell-1">Phases<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">Phase1<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">Phase2<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table-cell-1">Commencement Date<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">7 April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">28 April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table-cell-1">Last of Registration<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">5 April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">26 April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table-cell-1">Last Date of Refund<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">20 April 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-cell-2">10 May 2016<br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to have thicker borders in your cells, you can use: `border-width: 10px;` in your other css classes, where you can change the value as you like.

Comment: Please look at the complete code now. The table borders are not displayed within the list.